# How to save vim-vixen configuration?

Tags: firefox-extensions

https://github.com/ueokande/vim-vixen
In vixen's config page I can see configuration but I can't save my new configuration, just change is not work, and I can't find out some things similar to "save button" in vixen's config page

```
$ firefox-esr --version
Mozilla Firefox 60.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Below the configuration window you have two buttons - disable and remove.
If you make a change in the configuration window you can click **disable** button and then **enable** to re-enable the plugin and your changes will be saved.